# calling javascript function using struts 2 hyperlink tag?

Tags: javascript, struts2

i have below code snippet in my jsp but it does not call addCustomer function.

```
 <s:a href="javascript:addCustomer()">Add Customer</s:a>
```

Am i missing something in using s:a tag?

The html code generated coressponding to s:a tag is

```
<a href="javascript:addCustomer();" tabindex="-1">Add Customer</a>
```

Though when i use below code snippet javascript function gets executed. I am not getting whats the issue in using s:a tag?

```
<a href="#" onclick = "addCustomer();">Add Custome</a>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a Struts 2 tag for something that doesn't have anything to do with Struts 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
<a href="#" onclick = "myfunction(12);">Click</a>
```

javascript function

```
function myfunction(var1)
        {
                var params =var1; //values for passing to struts if any
                var resultStringX = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"mystruts2action.action", // struts2 action call
                data: params,
                async: false
                }).responseText;
                resultStringX=$.trim(resultStringX);  // the returning result will be stored in resultStringX variable
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like these three..

1.

```
<s:url value="http://www.mkking.com" var="mkyongURL" />
<s:a href="%{mkyongURL}">J2EE web development tutorials</s:a>
```

2.

```
<s:a href="http://www.google.com">Google search engine</s:a>
```

3.

```
<s:url action="aTagaAction.action" var="aURL" />
<s:a href="%{aURL}">aTagAction</s:a>
```

Comment: want to call javascript function

Comment: use your function in href like u hav written and check